# Result Code enumeration VBScript

Tags: vbscript

So i have a question, i have a little script that updates my windows pc unattended, but to make sure it actually installs the updates i want to log it. Now its almost done, but i want to add a last thing.

I found a string that defines the possible results of a download, install, uninstall, or verification operation on an update. But it shows in in numbers, from 0 to 5. But when it shows a certain number i want to add the meaning of it behind it like this:

```
0 = not started
1 = in progress
2 = succeeded
3 = succeededwitherrors
4 = failed
5 = aborted
```

Does anyone knows how this can be done with something like an If function?

Many thanks,

Kind regards

EDIT (added full code):

```
option explicit

Dim fso, f, ssDefault, ssManagedServer, ssWindowsUpdate, ssOthers, updates
Dim strComputer, intSearchStartChar, updateSession, updateSearcher 
Dim searchResult, I, update, updatesToDownload, addThisUpdate, downloader, updatesToInstall, rebootMayBeRequired, installer, installationResult, objWMIService, colOS, objOS
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\outpuut.txt", 8, True)

'End of Script

'ServerSelection values
ssDefault = 0
ssManagedServer   = 1
ssWindowsUpdate   = 2
ssOthers          = 3

strComputer = "." ' Local Computer

'InStr values
intSearchStartChar = 1

dim strTitle

Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()

updateSearcher.ServerSelection = ssWindowsUpdate
Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")

f.WriteLine "<Gevonden updates>"

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
f.WriteLine "<Update info>"    
f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "<titel>" & update.Title & "</titel>"
f.WriteLine "<status>" & update.MsrcSeverity & "</status>"
f.WriteLine "<verborgen>" & update.IsHidden & "</verborgen>"
f.WriteLine "<omschrijving>" & update.Description & "</omschrijving>"
f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "</Update info>"

Next

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
f.WriteLine "<Update info>"
   f.WriteLine "<Error> Geen updates beschikbaar </Error>"
f.WriteLine "</Update info>"
f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "</Gevonden updates>"    
   WScript.Quit
End If

f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "</Gevonden updates>"


f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "<Gedownloadde updates>"

Set updatesToDownload = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    addThisUpdate = false
    If update.InstallationBehavior.CanRequestUserInput = true Then
        f.WriteLine I + 1 & "> skipping: " & update.Title & _
        " because it requires user input"
    Else
        If update.EulaAccepted = false Then
            f.WriteLine I + 1 & "> note: " & update.Title & _
            " has a license agreement that must be accepted:"

                update.AcceptEula()
                addThisUpdate = true
        Else
            addThisUpdate = true
        End If
    End If
    If addThisUpdate = true Then
f.WriteLine "<Download info>"        
f.WriteLine "<titel>" & update.Title & "</titel>"
f.WriteLine "<downloadpriority>" & update.DownloadPriority & "</downloadproirity>"
f.WriteLine "<isdownloaded>" & update.IsDownloaded & "</isdownloaded>"
f.WriteLine "<maxdownloadsize>" & update.MaxDownloadSize & "</maxdownloadsize>"
f.WriteLine "<mindownloadsize>" & update.MinDownloadSize & "</mindownloadsize>"
f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "</Download info>"  
        updatesToDownload.Add(update)
    End If
Next

If updatesToDownload.Count = 0 Then
    f.WriteLine "All applicable updates were skipped."
    WScript.Quit
End If

Set downloader = updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
downloader.Updates = updatesToDownload
downloader.Download()

Set updatesToInstall = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

rebootMayBeRequired = false



For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    If update.IsDownloaded = true Then

        updatesToInstall.Add(update)    
        If update.InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior > 0 Then
            rebootMayBeRequired = true
        End If
    End If
Next

f.WriteLine vbCRLF & "</Gedownloadde updates>"

If updatesToInstall.Count = 0 Then
    f.WriteLine "<Error>No updates were successfully downloaded.</Error>"
    WScript.Quit
End If

If rebootMayBeRequired = true Then

End If

f.WriteLine "<geinstalleerde updates>"
    Set installer = updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
    installer.Updates = updatesToInstall
    Set installationResult = installer.Install()

    'Output results of install
    f.WriteLine "<Installatie resultaat>" & installationResult.ResultCode & "</Installatie resultaat>"
    f.WriteLine "<Reboot nodig>" & installationResult.RebootRequired & "</Reboot nodig>" & vbCRLF 
    f.WriteLine "Listing of updates installed " & _
    "and individual installation results:" 

    For I = 0 to updatesToInstall.Count - 1
    f.writeline "<Updates resultaat>"
    f.writeline "<Titel>" & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & "</Titel>"
    f.writeline "<ResultaatCode>" & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode & "</ResultaatCode>"

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    f.writeline d(0) = "not started"
    f.writeline d(2) = "succeeded"
Next

f.WriteLine "</geinstalleerde updates>"


Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!\\" & _
            strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOS in colOS
    objOS.Rebooot()
Next

f.close
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to map (e)nums (keys) to something readable (values):

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> d("0") = "not started"
>> d("5") = "aborted"
>> k = "5"
>> WScript.Echo k, d(k)
>>
5 aborted
>>
```

(I assume, your keys are strings; if not,

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> d(0) = "not started"
>> d(5) = "aborted"
```

will work as well.)

**Update wrt comment/added code:**

Create/Fill the dictionary before the loop:

```
...
f.WriteLine "<Gevonden updates>"
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d("0") = "not started"
...
d("5") = "aborted"
For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
...
```

Assuming `update.MsrcSeverity` contains the (e)nums you are interested in, change

```
f.WriteLine "<status>" & update.MsrcSeverity & "</status>"
```

to:

```
f.WriteLine "<status>" & update.MsrcSeverity & ": " & d(update.MsrcSeverity) & "</status>"
```

(not really tested; the dictionary d deserves a better name; double checking the data (sub) type of `update.MsrcSeverity` is advisable.)

**Update II:**

Perhaps:

```
f.writeline "<ResultaatCode>" & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode & "</ResultaatCode>"
```

==>

```
s = d(installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode)
f.writeline "<ResultaatCode>" & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode & " (" & s & ")" &"</ResultaatCode>"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I've tryed to edit the code with your help, but i dont really know what i am doing wrong at the moment.. because it seems to not work.. i added the full code at my begin post. Maybe you could have a look at it?

Comment: Hi, i still dont manage to get it working... its not the Update.MsrcSeverity but is the installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode. So i replaced what you adviced me with this code installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode and its still not working... now when i try to launch the vbscript and i have a look at the log file, it stops at the point where i added the code.

Comment: Well, i still cant manage to get it working. It did worked once but now its not working at all...

Comment: @user3611729 sorry to hear that, but without a crystal ball I can't help you. Probably you'll have to start with a minimal working script and add features step by step to isolate the point of failure. BTW: 'does not work' does not work as a description of a problem.

Comment: Okay, i am going through it all once again, other wise ill post the exact steps what i do because as of right now i only get to see:

<ResultCode>2: </ResultCode>

and not

<ResultCode>2: Succesfull</ResultCode>

Comment: So finally i got it up and running! Now i just need something else (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681272/start-searching-for-updates-after-reboot-vbscript?noredirect=1#comment36383166_23681272) Many thanks for your help sir! Unfortunatly i cant "thumb up" yet

Answer (score 1):

```
function resultcode(strCode)
    result = "Unknown"
    if strCode = 0 then result = "not started"
    if strCode = 1 then result = "in progress"
    if strCode = 2 then result = "succeeded"
    if strCode = 3 then result = "succeededwitherrors"
    if strCode = 4 then result = "failed"
    if strCode = 5 then result = "aborted"
    resultcode = result
end function
```

Then call it with

```
I + 1 & "> " & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & ": " & resultcode(installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode)
```